# py.test: how to forbid to load conftest files in upper directories

Tags: python, pytest

I have structure like this:

```
conftest.py
dir/conftest.py
dir/test_my.py
```

When I change directory to `dir` and run `py.test test_my.py`, my tests start with configuration, declared in the outer `conftest.py` (which is out of `dir`). Is there any way to change pytest behaviour: to load `conftest`-file only from the local directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [confcutdir](http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html?highlight=confcutdir#confval-confcutdir) option to specify where pytest should stop searching for `conftest.py` files.